# Filter specific key value aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

We are currently using Elasticsearch to power a product list on a website. The filtering is also managed by Elasticsearch, and we are running into a problem with a key value aggregation and filtering.

**TL;DR:**
Doing an aggregation on key / value field "features" with filter applied:

```
{
  "features": {
    "global": {},
    "aggregations": {
      "features": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "features",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "minimum_should_match": "1",
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "features.code": "brand"
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      "should": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "features.value.code": "CKJ"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "aggregations": {
          "features": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "features"
            },
            "aggregations": {
              "key": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "features.code",
                  "min_doc_count": 1,
                  "size": 50,
                  "order": {
                    "_term": "asc"
                  }
                },
                "aggregations": {
                  "value": {
                    "terms": {
                      "size": 50,
                      "order": {
                        "_term": "asc"
                      },
                      "min_doc_count": 1,
                      "field": "features.value.descriptions.description.NL"
                    },
                    "aggregations": {
                      "code": {
                        "terms": {
                          "field": "features.value.code"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Question: Can we write this so we can choose which key gets the filter (instead of all keys).

**Long version:**

This is how our data looks:

```
       { 
     "price": 59.95,
    "id": "123456789",
    "colours": [
        {
            "id": 39672,
            "description": {
                "EN": "Multi colour",
                "NL": "Multi kleur",
                "FR": "Multi couleur",
                "DE": "Multi colour"
            },
            "images": [ ],
            "primaryimage": "4055157573965.jpg",
            "swatch": "4055157573965.jpg"
        }
        ,
        {
            "id": 40383,
            "description": {
                "EN": "Multi colour",
                "NL": "Multi kleur",
                "FR": "Multi couleur",
                "DE": "Multi colour"
            },
            "images": [ ],
            "primaryimage": "4055157573637.jpg",
            "swatch": "4055157573637.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "size": [
        "36"
    ],
    "features": [
        {
            "id": null,
            "code": "brand",
            "key": {
                "NL": "Merk",
                "FR": "Marque",
                "DE": "Marke",
                "EN": "Brand"
            },
            "value": {
                "descriptions": [
                    {
                        "description": {
                            "DE": "BRAND"
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        "description": {
                            "NL": "BRAND"
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        "description": {
                            "EN": "BRAND"
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        "description": {
                            "FR": "BRAND"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "code": "brand"
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            "id": null,
            "code": "gender",
            "key": {
                "FR": "Genre",
                "DE": "Geschlecht",
                "EN": "Gender",
                "NL": "Geslacht"
            },
            "value": {
                "descriptions": [
                    {
                        "description": {
                            "FR": "Dames"
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        "description": {
                            "NL": "Dames"
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        "description": {
                            "EN": "Dames"
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        "description": {
                            "DE": "Dames"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "code": "1"
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            "id": null,
            "code": "groupLevel1",
            "key": {
                "DE": "GroupLevel1",
                "FR": "GroupLevel1",
                "NL": "GroupLevel1",
                "EN": "GroupLevel1"
            },
            "value": {
                "descriptions": [
                    {
                        "description": {
                            "EN": "Level1"
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        "description": {
                            "FR": "Level1s"
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        "description": {
                            "NL": "Level1"
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        "description": {
                            "DE": "Level1"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "code": "119D"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is (a simplified) query we are running on the data:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": "18",
  "sort": [
    "_score"
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "online": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "visible": true
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "web_product.user": 111
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "id_navigation": "281"
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "features",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "minimum_should_match": "1",
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "features.code": "brand"
                        }
                      }
                    ],
                    "should": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "features.value.code": "CKJ"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "include": [
      "*.NL",
      "id_product",
      "product_code",
      "colours.id",
      "colours.primaryimage",
      "colours.swatch",
      "price"
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
"colours": {
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id_navigation": "281"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "online": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "visible": true
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "web_product.id_tenant": 115
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "features",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "minimum_should_match": "1",
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "features.code": "brand"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "should": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "features.value.code": "CKJ"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "colours": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "colours.description.NL.facet",
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "size": 50,
        "order": {
          "_term": "asc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
    "features": {
      "global": {},
      "aggregations": {
        "features": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "id_navigation": "281"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "online": 1
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "visible": true
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "web_product.user": 111
                  }
                },
                {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "features",
                    "query": {
                      "bool": {
                        "minimum_should_match": "1",
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "term": {
                              "features.code": "brand"
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "should": [
                          {
                            "term": {
                              "features.value.code": "CKJ"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "features": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "features"
              },
              "aggregations": {
                "key": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "features.code",
                    "min_doc_count": 1,
                    "size": 50,
                    "order": {
                      "_term": "asc"
                    }
                  },
                  "aggregations": {
                    "value": {
                      "terms": {
                        "size": 50,
                        "order": {
                          "_term": "asc"
                        },
                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                        "field": "features.value.descriptions.description.NL"
                      },
                      "aggregations": {
                        "code": {
                          "terms": {
                            "field": "features.value.code"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query works perfectly and filters the data and aggregations nicely. 
Important in this example are the 2 aggregations: "colours" and "features". Both aggregations are filtered to show the corresponding facets to the query. 
We are working with multiselects though, so if we filter on colours, we will not filter the aggregation to show all other available colours. This is all working fine for all of our aggregations except the features aggregation.

The features aggregation is a key value aggregation, and will return multiple facets:

```
    "features": {

    "doc_count": 2327,
    "features": {
        "doc_count": 11,
        "features": {
            "doc_count": 66,
            "key": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": "brand",
                        "doc_count": 11,
                        "value": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "Calvin Klein",
                                    "doc_count": 11,
                                    "code": {
                                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                        "buckets": [
                                            {
                                                "key": "CKJ",
                                                "doc_count": 11
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        "key": "gender",
                        "doc_count": 11,
                        "value": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "WOMEN",
                                    "doc_count": 11,
                                    "code": {
                                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                        "buckets": [
                                            {
                                                "key": "WOMEN",
                                                "doc_count": 11
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        "key": "groupLevel1",
                        "doc_count": 11,
                        "value": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "BLAZERS",
                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                    "code": {
                                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                        "buckets": [
                                            {
                                                "key": "520300",
                                                "doc_count": 1
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "key": "CARDIGANS",
                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                    "code": {
                                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                        "buckets": [
                                            {
                                                "key": "540200",
                                                "doc_count": 1
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "key": "HEMDEN KORTE MOUWEN",
                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                    "code": {
                                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                        "buckets": [
                                            {
                                                "key": "510000",
                                                "doc_count": 1
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "key": "HEMDEN LANGE MOUWEN",
                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                    "code": {
                                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                        "buckets": [
                                            {
                                                "key": "510100",
                                                "doc_count": 1
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "key": "JURKEN",
                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                    "code": {
                                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                        "buckets": [
                                            {
                                                "key": "560100",
                                                "doc_count": 1
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "key": "ROKKEN",
                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                    "code": {
                                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                        "buckets": [
                                            {
                                                "key": "560000",
                                                "doc_count": 1
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "key": "SJAALS",
                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                    "code": {
                                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                        "buckets": [
                                            {
                                                "key": "590700",
                                                "doc_count": 1
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "key": "SWEATERS",
                                    "doc_count": 2,
                                    "code": {
                                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                        "buckets": [
                                            {
                                                "key": "540000",
                                                "doc_count": 2
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "key": "T-SHIRTS LANGE MOUWEN",
                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                    "code": {
                                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                        "buckets": [
                                            {
                                                "key": "530100",
                                                "doc_count": 1
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    "key": "TRUIEN",
                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                    "code": {
                                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                        "buckets": [
                                            {
                                                "key": "540100",
                                                "doc_count": 1
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }

                ]
            }
        }
    }

},
"colours": {

    "doc_count": 11,
    "colours": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "Blauw",
                "doc_count": 1
            }
            ,
            {
                "key": "Grijs",
                "doc_count": 4
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

Colours filter added for comparison.

Now when we select an feature facet on the frontend, we of course want to have multiselect too. However when we apply the filter to the features aggregation all keys are filtered, resulting in a not-multi-selectable facet. If we remove the filter on the features aggregation, the other keys are not filtered resulting in an incorrect facet selection.

So my question after all of this is: can we filter a value/key aggregation based on the key? Logic would go like this: if key == brand then do not filter else filter

If more examples are needed I can add them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you maybe come up with a simplified version of your problem, that preserves the issue you are having with out a ton of extraneous details?

Comment: I added a simpler version, hope this is more clear.

Comment: Have you tried anything with the [global aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation.html)?

Comment: Yes, we are already using the global filter to be able to do multi select.

Comment: Ah. Then I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. I'll come back later when I have a little more time. Again, if you could simplify the problem you will be more likely to get a coherent answer.